# Power Query · Dynamic column calculation · M Syntax

Tags: syntax, metadata, powerquery, m

I need to do a new column as a subtraction from two (year from previous year), every year will change. So, the first value must be: 49.443

[image]

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
"[" & Text.From(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow())-1) & "]" -
"[" & Text.From(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow())-2) & "]"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this answered, but I think you're almost there.

`DateTime.LocalNow` is correct, but you can't use `"["` and `&` because that will result a string literal -- whereas what you want is dynamic field access using something like `Record.Field` function (within row context of `each` statement).

This is a table containing some mock/dummy data. Last column (`differencia anual`) is basically the difference between previous year's values and the values from two years ago (which at the time of writing are 2018 and 2017 respectively).

[image: Example table]

Try something like:

```
let
    mockData = Table.FromColumns({{11..20}, List.Numbers(40, 10, 2)}, type table [2017 = Int64.Type, 2018 = Int64.Type]),
    annualDifference = 
        let
            currentYear = Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),
            previousYearHeader = Number.ToText(currentYear - 1),
            twoYearsAgoHeader = Number.ToText(currentYear - 2),
            differenceColumn = Table.AddColumn(mockData, "diferencia anual", each Record.Field(_, previousYearHeader) - Record.Field(_, twoYearsAgoHeader), type number)
        in differenceColumn
in
    annualDifference
```

Since you are using `DateTime.LocalNow`, the columns being subtracted will be determined by your computer's system clock -- which I think is what you wanted.